# Weird crash when first tapping UITextField

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

I have a text field in my Cocos2d app and when I tap it to start typing, the app just crashes. I don't have much more to explain, here's my code:
.h:

```
@interface myScene : CCLayer <UITextFieldDelegate> { ....... }
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UITextField *first;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UITextField *second;
```

.mm:

```
    @implementation myScene
    @synthesize first, second;
    ......
        first = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0, 160.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        first.placeholder = @"first";
        first.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  // no auto correction suppor
        first.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault; // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        first.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        first.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;    // has a clear 'x' button to the right
        first.autocapitalizationType =  UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);  
        first.transform = transform;
        first.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        first.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [first setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]];
        first.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        first.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        first.delegate = self;  // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: first];


        second = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130.0, 160.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        second.placeholder = @"second";
        second.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        second.transform = transform;
        second.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        second.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [second setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]];
        second.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        second.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        second.secureTextEntry = YES;
        second.delegate = self; // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: second];

...............


    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        // the user pressed the "Done" button, so dismiss the keyboard
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```

I'm running on Xcode 4 with iOS 4.3 and when I tap one of the fields I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and Xcode points me to main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Xcode indicates the line: `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");`

Thanks.

Comment: Jhaliya is right. You do have more to explain, and that is the exact message and other behavior that you get when your app crashes.

Comment: When the crash occurs, type bt into the debugger and paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think thats the best way to add a text field in your openGL view in fact im not sure it will work. You probably either need to have your fields in a UIViewController subclass and then add the view of that class to your `openGLView`, or there is a good UIViewWrapper you could get [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889). It lets you add UIView elements to your CCLayer. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try adding NSZombieEnabled as described in http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

It should write something more instresting than "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message